# Sending Serialized Object from java server to android client

Tags: java, android, sockets, object, serialization

Kindly, I am having a java server and an android mobile client, the server gets an object from database (revokedUser) and sends it to the android client.

However the client receives the object by Object input stream but blocks at the readobject phase and I don't know why

In other mean, the first UIhelper in the client code is printing a reference while the second UIhelper is not

Please need your help

Server Code

```
    public void revokeUser(String userid){

            try {
                Connection conn = Config.getConnection();       
                PreparedStatement stat = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

                stat.setString(1,userid);
                stat.setInt(2, listno);
                stat.setInt(3, counter);
                stat.execute();
                revokeUserzz(userid,listno, counter);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }}


private void revokeUserzz(String userid, int listno, int counter) {

    RevokedUser revoke = new RevokedUser();

revoke.setuserName(userid);
revoke.setlistNumber(listno);
revoke.setcounter(counter);

try { 
        ServerSocket serversocket = new ServerSocket(4400);
        System.out.println("listening: 8888");
        Socket socket = serversocket.accept();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        oos.writeObject(revoke);
        System.out.println("UserName: " +revoke.getuserName());
        System.out.println("ListNumber: " +revoke.getlistNumber());
        System.out.println("Counter: " +revoke.getcounter());

    serversocket.close();
    socket.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

Client Code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
    Socket socket;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    try {
        socket = new Socket("192.168.1.115", 4400);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        UIHelper.displayText(this, R.id.textView1, "Object =\n" +ois.toString());

        RevokedUser revoke = (RevokedUser) ois.readObject();
        UIHelper.displayText(this, R.id.textView3, "Object =\n" +revoke.getuserName().toString());
    }
}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Serialized Code

```
public class RevokedUser implements Serializable {
```

private static final long serialVersionUID = -86055680657258429L;

```
private int listNumber;
private int counter;
private String userName;

public RevokedUser() {
}

public int getlistNumber() {
    return listNumber;
}

public void setlistNumber(int listNumber) {
    this.listNumber = listNumber;
}

public int getcounter() {
    return counter;
}

enter code here

public void setcounter(int counter) {
    this.counter = counter;
}
enter code here
public String getuserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setuserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

@Override
public String toString() {

    return "RevockedUser{" +
            "userIds='" + userName + '\'' +
            ", listNumber=" + listNumber +
            ", counter=" + counter +
            '}';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One potential problem is the way that you are closing stuff in the server.

If you close the Socket without closing the output stream first, it is possible that the stuff you previously wrote to the stream won't get flushed ... and the client won't see it.

(I'm not convinced this is the actual problem ... but I think you should fix it anyway.)

---

A second problem is that your server-side and client-side is liable to leak file descriptors.  The problem is that if an exception gets thrown while you have a Socket, the exception may not get closed.  Do this too often, and your will run out application will run out of either file descriptors or IP port numbers.

The correct way to deal with this is to close the Socket (and ServerSocket) in a `finally` clause ... so that it always gets closed.

Comment: Agree. You need an oos.flush() prior to closing the socket.

Answer (score 0):

'ois'.toString() doesn't yield anything interesting.

You should always close the output stream you have wrapped around the socket, not the socket itself. Otherwise you can lose data.